# Twitter card player configuration issue

Tags: php, twitter, video-streaming, twitter-card

I am trying to configure twitter card player, included meta tags according to there docs and request for approval and got rejected twice.
these are my meta tags

```
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="player">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@GauravDhimanG">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Testing video">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="This is a sample video.">
<meta name="twitter:image:width" content="480">
<meta name="twitter:image:height" content="480">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo $image = $https_url."/example.png"; ?>">
<meta name="twitter:player" content="<?php echo $player = $https_url."/container.html"; ?>">
<meta name="twitter:player:width" content="480">
<meta name="twitter:player:height" content="480">
<meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="">
<meta name="twitter:player:stream:content_type" content="video/mp4">
```

both image and player url is correct and working.
I dont know what i am doing wrong into it .
What i want to achieve is when someone put our site video link in tweet it will be able to play the video in twitter(no redirection to any site) as youtube , cnbctv 18 and  some other sites are doing.
Please help me out on this.